# Biblioteca em C/C++ para manipular imagens

Tags: c, c++

Gostaria de saber qual biblioteca usar, que seja de fácil instalação  tanto pra Windows quanto pra Linux, para manipular imagens( do tipo png, jpg, etc) em C/C++ ?

Gostaria de abrir e salvá-la em uma matriz para poder trabalhar com esses dados bem como mostra-la em uma janela depois( exibir a imagem).

Só precisa fazer isso mesmo. Não precisa ser uma OpenCV da vida.

Comment: Para exibir uma imagem em uma janela o que você quer não é uma biblioteca de "manipulação de imagens", mas uma biblioteca de "interface gráfica". Nenhuma biblioteca de manipulação de imagens tem funções para abrir uma janela e mostrar imagens; todas as bibliotecas de interface gráfica (SDL, IUP, GTK+, TK, FLTK, Fox Toolkit, Qt, wxWidgets, etc) o fazem. As bibliotecas de formatos gráficos (libjpeg, libpng, libtiff, etc.) só lêem e escrevem matrizes de pontos em seus formatos respectivos.

Comment: eu uso stb_image com OpenGl

Answer (score 1):

O ideal seria trabalhar diretamente com a libpng ou a libjpeg. É verdade que são bibliotecas que, a uma primeira vista, parecem complexas e esotéricas mas elas dão o que você e são somente isso - abrir uma imagem do formato delas e te dar um ponteiro para uma array com os dados da imagem. Um exemplo de leitura de arquivo com a libpng: http://zarb.org/~gc/html/libpng.html

Se você não quiser trabalhar com o baixo nivel das várias bibliotecas de carga de imagem não tem jeito senão usar algo que as envolva em uma camada de abstração, como a ITK, a OpenCV ou a VTK (essa ultima carrega também capacidades de exibição da imagem). A SDL também seria uma boa alternativa e é mais simples de usar que as que eu citei acima.

Quanto a facilidade de instalação, depende de você saber usar ou não o CMake. Se você souber usar o Cmake toda biblioteca de c/c++ se torna fácil de usar, bastando por o diretório dos .h e o caminho pro .lib no Cmake segundo as regras dele. Se você não souber usar o Cmake, você terá problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia tentar a biblioteca [`CxImage`](https://cpp.zeef.com/faraz.fallahi).

Documentação: http://www.xdp.it/cximage/

[Nesse site contêm todos os links de bibliotecas](https://cpp.zeef.com/faraz.fallahi), na aba *Image Processing*, você pode encontrar outras opções viáveis.